# Trying to export a range in Excel to CSV with only cells that contain data

Tags: excel, csv, vba

Good afternoon all,

I am building an excel sheet for my coworkers to use to generate CSV files. I need to get an output with header row and then all the data from the sheet. It will be no more than 40 rows, but could be less rows. I currently have a lot of formulas in the sheet doing the heavy lifting for my coworkers on things like generating usernames/etc from the input data. I need to have them click a button and get the CSV file on the other end. My current issues are as follows.

1.) my CSV contains double quotes on every field, even though commas should not be in the input data. I need to prevent this as the program we are feeding these csv files to does not like the double quotes AT ALL. Yes, I know you can open it in notepad and replace all to remove them but im trying to build a one click solution as some of the folks using this are not very tech savvy.

2.) my macro is exporting all forty rows of data currently. I need it to only export the rows that contain data. Theoretically with the formulas built there should be no "partial" rows, only a full row or a blank row.

3.) When generating the CSV file its not appending a filetype at all, I need it to specify a .txt. filetype if at all possible as again, the program we are feeding these to is very picky.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim filename As String
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer

filename = InputBox("Please enter file name", "Save as CSV", "CSV_" & Format(Now, "DD_MM_yyyy"))
myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & filename

Set rng = Range("A1:J41")

Open myFile For Output As #1

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

            cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

                If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                    Write #1, cellValue
                        Else
                    Write #1, cellValue,
                End If
        Next j
    Next i

Close #1
```

End Sub

Comment: Where do these double quotes come from? Do they appear when you fill your .csv or are they in the existing cellValues?

Comment: After half an hour of experimenting with your code, I figured that there as actually a super easy way to do this. Just use 'Save As' -> Choose CSV -> If you're workbook has several Sheets a prompt will pop up, asking you if you only want to save the active worksheet. Push 'Yes' -> you are done

Comment: Just a quick area of clarification.
You said that not all 40 rows may have data. Is the data in consecutive rows or could it have blanks between? i.e. if there are 5 rows of dat are they in rows 1-5 or could they bee in rows 1,2,4,6,9?

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code would have to look like. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get rid of the double quotes, maybe someone else has an idea for that.

```
Sub csvExport()
Dim filename As String
Dim myFile As String, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

filename = "\" & InputBox("Please enter file name", "Save as CSV", "CSV_" & Format(Now, "DD_MM_yyyy")) & ".txt"
myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & filename

    Set ws = Worksheets("YOURSHEETNAME")

    With ws

    Open myFile For Output As #1

    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count

            cellValue = .Cells(i, j).Value
                If j = .UsedRange.Columns.Count Then
                    Write #1, cellValue
                        Else
                    Write #1, cellValue,
                End If
        Next j
    Next i

Close #1
End With

End Sub
```